# Should I set expiration on caches of "constant" results in Redis?

Tags: caching, redis

I have a few queries to a database that return absolutely constant responses, i.e. some entries on this database are never changed after written.

I'm wondering if I'm to implement caching on them with Redis, should I set an expiration time?

Pros and cons of *not* doing that -

Pros: Users will always benefit from caching (except for the first query)

Cons: The number of these entries to be queried is growing. So Redis will end up using more and more memory.

**Edit**

To give more context, the queries run quite slow. Each of them may take seconds. It will be beneficial to minimize the number of users that experience this.

Also, each of these results has size around the magnitude a several kB; The number (not size) of entries may be increasing for 1 per minute.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering with questions. Still waiting for enough reputation to comment and clarify.

#### Answering your direct question:

Are the number of queries you expect unbounded?
No: You could improve first user experience by triggering the queries on startup and leaving in cache. Other responses that are expected to change you could attach a TTL to and use any of the following maxmemory-policy settings in the config: `volatile-ttl`, `allkeys-lru`, 'volatile-lfu`, or` volatile-random` to only evict keys with TTLs.

Yes: Prioritize these by attaching a TTL and updating each time it's requested to keep in cache as long as possible and use any of the memory management policies that best fit the rest of your use case.

#### Related concerns:

If these are really static values, why are you querying a database rather than reading from a flat file of constants generated once and read at startup?

Have you attempted to optimize your queries?